# Cakephp 3 redirect not working if exception is after

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect, cookies, cakephp-3.0

I have an action in a controller where i call to a function that checks if a cookie is set, if the cookie is not set then it should redirect to somewhere else.

In the same controller i have an evaluation for some variables, if they're not set then throw a forbidden exception but even when the cookie is not set it's not redirecting and the forbidden message appears

The correct action should be redirect and never evaluate for the variables when the cookie doesn't exist or at least that's what i need.

This function is in appController

```
public function isCookieSet(){
  if(!$this->Cookie->check('cookie')){
    return $this->redirect($this->referer());
  }
}
```

And the code inside my controller

```
public function editarImg($negocio_id=null){    

    $this->isCookieSet(); //should redirect here

    //but executes until here
    if((!isset($this->perRol['crear_negocios']) || $this->perRol['crear_negocios']==0) || 
      (!isset($this->perRol['cargar_elim_imagenes']) || $this->perRol['cargar_elim_imagenes']==0)){
      throw new ForbiddenException($this->getMensajeError(403));
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: This is odd, i have used the same structure on cakephp 2 and works fine. it could be a bug of cakephp 3??

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question can be rewritten (for clarity) like so:

```
public function editarImg($negocio_id=null){    
    if(!$this->Cookie->check('cookie')){
        $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }

    // more code
```

The return value of the call to `redirect` is being ignored, "more code" is *always* executed.

This is not how the method `redirect` is expected to be called, as [mentioned in the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#redirecting-to-other-pages) (emphasis added):

> The method will return the response instance with appropriate headers set. **You should return the response instance from your action** to prevent view rendering and let the dispatcher handle actual redirection.

This is also mentioned [in the migration guide](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html):

> The signature of `Cake\Controller\Controller::redirect()` has been changed to `Controller::redirect(string|array $url, int $status = null)`. The 3rd argument $exit has been dropped. The method can no longer send response and exit script, instead it returns a Response instance with appropriate headers set.

### Code example

The code in the question needs to be the equivalent of this:

```
public function editarImg($negocio_id=null){    
    if(!$this->Cookie->check('cookie')){
        return $this->redirect($this->referer()); # <- return the response object
    }

    // more code
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. For me is still weird becouse this worked fine in cake 2.
But with your clarification if come up with something. In the controller i placed this instead and works

[code]if($this->isCookieSet()){ 
  return $this->isCookieSet();
}

And that makes the redirection before reaching for the forbidden message

Comment: I don't really understand the confusion. In 2.x it was not necessary to return the result of calling redirect, _in 3.x it is_. I don't understand what is weird about this.

Comment: It's worth noting that the API documentation might be somewhat misleading because it does say `Script execution is halted after the redirect.` http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Controller.Controller.html#_redirect

Comment: @BadHorsie I have removed that comment from master (next version), it is a left over from <3.0 when [the comment was accurate](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.0.0/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php#L679-L688).

Comment: FWIW @AD7six it's still standing. Looks like I'll need to use core PHP header() instead.

Comment: @SarahKing what is "it" ? This question was about using the redirect function incorrectly. Either the same code error exists, or the question/problem you have is not related to this answer. Please ask a new question if you need to (also see [the docs on where to get help](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/where-to-get-help.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work:

```
public function isCookieSet(){
  if(!$this->Cookie->check('cookie')){

    // return $this->redirect($this->referer()); <- not working

    $this->response = $this->redirect($this->referer());
    $this->response->send();
    exit;

  }
}
```